# Comunicação serial PHP - linux

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, terminal, serial

Olá, fiz um código php para comunicação serial, este código funcionou no windows corretamente, porém estou tendo problemas com ele no linux. Para conseguir realizar a comunicação, preciso usar o comando -stty -F /dev/ttyS0 19200 -icanon. Se eu não utilizar o -icanon não funciona. Fazendo isso, consigo realizar apenas uma vez a comunicação serial, depois parece que o ubuntu fica aguardando algum retorno e não consigo mais ler os dados que necessito. Segue meu código:

```
$envio = fopen("/dev/ttyS0", "r+b");
fwrite($envio, "\x01\x04\x02\x3C\x00\x64\x30\x55");
$dadosHex = fread($envio, 75);
$run = substr($dadosHex, 113, 1);
fwrite($envio, "\x01\x04\x02\x3C\x00\x64\x30\x55");
$dadosHex1 = fread($envio, 75);
$run1 = substr($dadosHex1, 113, 1);
fclose($envio);
```

A variável $run retorna o valor correto, porém $run1 não retorna corretamente. Percebi que se fechar e abrir a comunicação as duas funcionam, porém não posso fazer isso pois preciso de velocidade.
Desculpem qualquer não formatação pois sou novo por aqui.

Muito Obrigado.

Comment: O que está conectado à porta serial e o que representa os comandos enviados?

Comment: Tem um CLP conectado na porta. Os comandos enviados são requisições de memórias dele. No caso ele está retornando valores de tensão, corrente, etc...

Comment: Tem certeza que o primeiro comando está completo? Não falta nenhum símbolo a ser enviado para sinalizar o fim do comando?